# i not find how in powershell pass through http autentification then use a webservices (lotus/domino)

Tags: web-services, http, powershell

We have here a domino/lotus webservices i want use with powershell.

probleme is in front of webservices lotus admin ask a http autentification.

how i can use this webservice??

here what i tryed first scrap the first page and get cookie.

```
$url = "http://xxxxxxx/names.nsf?Login"

$CookieContainer = New-Object System.Net.CookieContainer

$postData = "Username=user***&Password=pss***"

$buffer = [text.encoding]::ascii.getbytes($postData)

[net.httpWebRequest] $req = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
$req.method = "POST"
$req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US")
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate")
$req.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7")
$req.AllowAutoRedirect = $false
$req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$req.ContentLength = $buffer.length
$req.TimeOut = 50000
$req.KeepAlive = $true
$req.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive: 300");
$req.CookieContainer = $CookieContainer
$reqst = $req.getRequestStream()
$reqst.write($buffer, 0, $buffer.length)
$reqst.flush()
$reqst.close()
[net.httpWebResponse] $res = $req.getResponse()
$resst = $res.getResponseStream()
$sr = new-object IO.StreamReader($resst)
$result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
```

this seem work but now no idea how i can use cookie with a webservicesproxy???
or maybee a better way to do it?

ps: i success have this to work with c# + visualstudio (just the class reference is autobuilt and i don't understand half of this but it allow me to use .CookieContenaire on the generated webservice )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the built in webservice cmdlet?

```
    $webservice = New-WebServiceProxy -Uri "http://xxx/names.nsf?Login" -Credential (Get-Credential)
```